# C#: A general question about order of conditions in an if-statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

So I have the following code:

```
    public bool TryGetItem(Item searchItem, out Item listItem)
    {
        listItem = ItemList.Find(x => x.Blueprint == searchItem.Blueprint);

        if (listItem != null)  return true;
        else                   return false;
    }


    public bool TryAddItem(ItemInstance item)
    {
        Item listItem;

        if (item.isStackable && TryGetItem(item, out listItem)) // the is the line of interest
        {
            listItem.amount += item.amount;
            return true;
        }

        else if (...)
            ...
    }
```

This gives me an "Use of unassigned local variable" error for "listItem.amount"

However if I switch the order of the conditions in the if-statement, the error goes away?
why is that?

```
    public bool TryAddItem(ItemInstance item)
    {
        Item listItem;

        if (TryGetItem(item, out listItem) && item.isStackable)  // the is the line of interest
        {
            listItem.amount += item.amount;
            return true;
        }

        else if (...)
            ...
    }
```

I want it to be the first way, since there is no reason to search for something if the isStackable-bool is false anyway, any comments?

Comment: _Item listItem = null;_

Comment: Like @Steve suggested, or inline the variable declaration in the statement: `TryGetItem(item, out var listItem)`

Comment: I was surprised by this error so I tried reproducing it, but it works on my side. I wonder if there's something else about your code

Comment: @KevinGosse maybe you have different compiler version?

Comment: Hmm, it's probably because of lazy evaluation. When the first operand of `&&` is `false` the second one isn't needed to be evaluated, it's already clear the operation is `false`. Now in your first code there is a chance that `TryGetItem(item, out listItem)` is never evaluated, if `item.isStackable` is `false`. Then `listItem` is not initialized. One might argue that then the `if` branch isn't entered and `listItem` therefore not accessed but the compiler may not be smart enough to "think" that far.

Comment: You can force eager evaluation by using `&` instead of `&&`. Or by changing the order of operands, as you already found out. Or completely redesign the code to make sure `TryGetItem()` is called independent of `item.isStackable`.

Comment: What (language?)compiler version are you using? Similar code does not generate such error for me, but possibly some versions of compiler could produce such an error due to short-circuiting evaluation of conditional statements and not fully fine-grained support for such cases.

Comment: @JohnG out requires the called code to initialize the out variable. Me as well cannot reproduce the problem using LinqPad 5 or 6

Comment: It's smart enough NOT to run that part of code :) that saves running for no reason.. the same would happen if it was an || (or) and the first did pass,, however it is important to know how if statements work, so you dont have important parts of code that never run..

Comment: read more here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/short-circuit-evaluation-in-c-sharp/

Comment: Remember that for definite assignment purposes, `if(A && B) C;` can be thought of as logically like `if (A) { if (B) C; }`.  If you think of it like that, does it become more clear why the definite assignment analysis is different in your two cases?

Comment: @EricLippert: could you elaborate? It seems to me that following that logic, we should expect to not see the "unassigned local" for both versions of the code. I.e. `if (B) C` even if evaluated independently of `A` would only allow `C` to be executed if the expression `B` is evaluated, and `B` should definitely assign the variable. In either order, `listItem` should be definitely assigned. Knowing that the definite assignment analysis is different in each case doesn't help (or, doesn't help _me_) understand better why the analysis is able to fully understand the 2nd example but not the 1st.

Comment: To the OP: I believe that the marked duplicates adequately address the vagaries of definite assignment analysis as they relate to short-circuiting operators. But if you think those are insufficient, say so and I or someone else will reopen the question to allow for a new answer. You should explain in detail though what you got from those duplicates, and why your question still remains (i.e. what you still don't understand).

Comment: All that said, I want to reiterate [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64233557/c-a-general-question-about-order-of-conditions-in-an-if-statement#comment113585914_64233557) and other similar ones. The fact is, I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you claim to see. I guess it's _possible_ an earlier version of the C# compiler has less rigorous definite assignment analysis, but I'm unable to verify your claim. It'd help if you'd post an actual [mcve] along with specifics about what compiler version you're using.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: My assumption based on the earlier comments pointing out that this is a no-repro was that either (1) the definite assignment defect is being reported on a line of code not shown by the original poster, or (2) there is something of type dynamic in the mix that the original poster has not shown; there are truly goofy things that can happen in this scenario when dynamic is in play. My comment was by way of encouraging the original poster to try rewriting the code to see if the observation made any more sense when the short circuit was explicit in the code.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: That is, my comment was intended to give the OP a new tool in their toolbox for analyzing the situation themselves; I was not intending to answer the question in the form of a comment. I see how it could be misread that way though; sorry for the unclarity.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: If you're curious as to what the crazy dynamic scenario is that breaks definite assignment analysis for this case, the answer to the puzzle is here: https://ericlippert.com/2018/11/19/a-dynamic-definite-assignment-puzzle-part-2/